# How can I set get request call type to 'document'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, get

How can I set get request call type to 'document' like the attached image? Its showing type "xhr" for me in network tab console.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,[image]

Comment: Hi  Zakaria Acharki - the above question you mentioned doesnt clear my question. Can you please let me know how to get the type "document"? Thanks

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.